# Nuxt 3: Element (DOM) not found in onMounted() hook with route change

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to access some DOM elements with the onMounted hook in Nuxt 3. This works perfectly on page reload.

**But when I access the page through a nuxt route I am getting an "Element not found" warning in the console.** And the gsap animation in this case is not working.

I am new to Nuxt 3, but to my understanding the DOM should be available at this point in the lifecycle?

```
onMounted(() => {
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('introimage'))
  // Header shrinking
  $gsap.to('.introimage__image', {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: '.introimage',
      start: 'top 200px',
      end: '300%',
      // pin: true,
      scrub: true,
      reverse: true,
      markers: false,
      toggleActions: 'restart none none reverse',
    },
    height: '0',
    duration: '3',
  })
})
```

Comment: You should use template refs rather than a query selector.

Comment: Yes, this works! I also needed to use .from({...}, height: '100%'), as the end value ('0%') was stored in the DOM element and therefore not visible.

Comment: I ran into this issue with a different library (including reload working), and kissu's suggestion to use template refs resolved it as well. Would love to know why, as my incomplete understanding was the same, that the DOM would be available in onMounted().

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with gsap. The way it worked for me was to add:

```
definePageMeta({
  pageTransition: {
    mode: 'default',
  },
});
```

[Quick StackBlitz as example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-s4ckbb?file=pages/index.vue)

Comment: The warning is gone and I can log the element. No transition though... Will test a bit more.